# Copying a 2D array to a dynamically allocated 2D array outside of the function

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, crash, copy

I have `fullNames`, which is a 2D array that has sorted full names in it and I want to copy its content into `sortedNames`, which is a 2D array that exists out side of this function. (I get `***sortedNames` as a parameter).

I dynamically allocated this array, but the copying does not succeed. The program crashes after the 4th attempt to copy a name from `fullNames` to `sortedNames`. Why?

`stringcpy` and `stringlen` are functions that I created. They do the same thing as `strcpy` and `strlen` does.

```
/*allocating memory for sortedNames*/
*sortedNames = (char**) malloc(n);/*n is the number of names*/

/*allocating memory for each sortedNames array*/
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    (*sortedNames)[i] = (char*) malloc(stringlen(fullNames[i])+1);
}


/*Copying fullNames into sortedNames*/

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    stringcpy((*sortedNames)[i],fullNames[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is n the number of names or the total size to be allocated>

Comment: [Obligatory reminder about not casting the reuslt of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: You should modify your question to include the function prototype.  It is `void myfunction(char ***sortedNames, const char **fullNames, size_t n)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not allocate enough memory for the array of pointers, you should allocate this way:

```
*sortedNames = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
```

Furthermore, why not use `strlen` and `strcpy` in place of `stringlen` and `stringcpy`? It this just a typo or do these function perform some extra function?

Regarding the cast on `malloc` return value, you could remove it if you do not intend to compile your code as C++ and write this:

```
*sortedNames = malloc(n * sizeof(**sortedNames));
```

Regarding the extra parentheses around `**sortedNames`, be aware that they are not necessary so you can remove them or not depending on your local style conventions.

Comment: [Obligatory reminder about not casting the reuslt of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Or simply `*sortedNames = malloc (n * sizeof **sortedNames);`

Comment: @Paul R: I beg to disagree, especially given the lack of information in the question.  Nowhere do we know the type of `sortedNames`. The explicit cast will prevent compilation if the type is not indeed `char ***sortedNames` or equivalent.

Comment: Well even in the particular case you mention you're just trading one potential problem for another. Casts in general (and especially redundant casts) are a code smell, and should be avoided other than as a last resort when no other more appropriate solution is available

Comment: @Paul R: I agree with you about casts in general.  In this particular case, I would use a macro to enforce type checking: `#define ALLOC(type, n) ((type*)calloc(n, sizeof(type)))`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Regarding the functions stringlen & stringcopy: It was a part of a homework assignment, and it was instructed not to use functions from stlib.h, and rather write them on my own.

Answer (score 0):

There should be 2 edits as the memory allocated may not be sufficient. This code :

```
(*sortedNames)[i] = (char*) malloc(n);
```

allocates memory for n bytes whiles you need memory for (n*the size of string) bytes.The second malloc may work as char occupies 1 byte. But try to use sizeof() to make it system independent.

The correct code would be :

```
 (*sortedNames)[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: Need the same comment by @PaulR :-)

Comment: Why, oh why, do you **cast malloc** -> don't. Meaning **get rid of** `(char *)`.

Comment: I beg to disagree, especially given the lack of information in the question.  Nowhere do we know the type of `sortedNames`. The explicit cast will prevent compilation if the type is not indeed `char ***sortedNames` or equivalent.